# Why the insertion of SMS with the content resolver sometimes return a uri with 0?

Tags: android, sms

The following code works on some tablets and don't on others with Android 7 (API 25) and 8 (API 27), Samsung and Huawai.
The problem is when inserting a new SMS in the database with the content resolver, it always returns a uri with a 0 ("content://sms/sent/0") instead of a uri with the sms id ("content://sms/sent/104", then "content://sms/sent/105").

```
   private val resolver = context.contentResolver

   fun saveSending(text: String, destAddress: String, threadId: Int = 0): Uri? {
        val uri = resolver.insert(Telephony.Sms.Sent.CONTENT_URI, ContentValues().apply {
            put(Telephony.Sms.BODY, text)
            put(Telephony.Sms.DATE, MainClock.clock.millis())
            put(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS, destAddress)
            put(Telephony.Sms.TYPE, Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_OUTBOX)
            put(Telephony.Sms.THREAD_ID, threadId)
            put(Telephony.Sms.READ, true)
            put(Telephony.Sms.SEEN, true)
        })
        return uri
    }
```

When querying after the SMS ("resolver.query"), it contains well its id
in the Telephony.Sms._ID column.

Is it a known Android bug ? Any workaround ?

Comment: have you enabled the permissions

Comment: Yes I can send, stock and do everything I want on all tablets. Just on some tablets the returned uri is 0. The SMS is always well sent and well stocked. I can find it with a query and get its ID that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it !
It was just that my app wasn't the **app by default to send messages**.
Thanks anyway